# using VB.net how do I pass credentials to ssrs report server?

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008-r2, credentials

I'm trying to pass credentials to the ssrs server to load the report as PDF but am getting 401 unauthorized error.

I have a vb.net web forms project that I'm working on and it is trying to load a report on a remote SQL Server 2008 r2 machine. I'm trying to load the report and have it download as a pdf. My code is supposed to load the file as a data stream which allows the user to save the file. Pointing the browser directly to the url of the report, I can get the PDF, but need to supply credentials. I'm trying to avoid the need to login to get the report. The code I'm using is supposed to pass credentials but instead of returning the report, I get 401 unauthorized error.

```
Dim ReportUrl As String = "http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReport%2fParishreport&rs:Command=Render&parameter=" & session("parameter") & "&rs:format=pdf"
Dim ReportWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
         Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ReportUrl), HttpWebRequest)
         'Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
         Request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "password")
         ReportWebResponse = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
         Dim ReportResponseStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ReportWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), New UnicodeEncoding)
         Dim objMemoryStream As New MemoryStream(New UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(ReportResponseStream.ReadToEnd()))
         Response.Clear()
         Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", objMemoryStream.Length.ToString())
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
         Response.OutputStream.Write(objMemoryStream.ToArray(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(objMemoryStream.Length))
         ReportResponseStream.Close()
         Response.Flush()

         Try
             Response.End()
         Catch
         End Try
```

I expected the browser to allow me to save the PDF or to display the pdf in the browser(Firefox built in PDF viewer). Using specified username and password, I get 401 unauthorized error. Using defaultcredentials, I get a blank PDF of the correct number of pages.

I have added the domain account to the report server: 1. using SQL server management studio  2. using report server web interface adding folder and report permissions.

What is the preferred method for supplying credentials to the reporting server such that a single domain account can be used to control users ability to view the report?

Comment: I figured out the the SSRS is using NTLM type 2 authentication against the active directory accounts and supports 56-bit & 128-bit encryption.The server is running windows 2008r2 if that matters.

Comment: It's been a year and I'm finally getting back to this. Any idea why my credentials are not working and I'm getting 401 unauthorized error?